# how to return a value from setinterval function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, setinterval

How to return a value from setinterval function?

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url:"<?php echo TESTMINE_APP_URL; ?>/ajax/export-details",
        data:'paginationHash='+paginationHash+'&exportType='+exportType+'&userId='+userId,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(requestId) 
        {
            var myVar = setInterval(function(){checkStatusOfRequest(requestId)},9000);
            alert(myVar);
        }
        });
```

Comment: What does `checkStatusOfRequest` do?

Comment: checkStatusOfRequest is a function will check the status of some process, I want to return back that status to called function.

Comment: in place of alert you can call another function that cant put this  value in session.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `setInterval`. A better way to accomplish what you want is to use the value you wish returned in the delayed function. Something like,

```
...
success: function (requestId) {
    setInterval(function () {
        var myVar = checkStatusOfRequest(requestId);
        alert(myVar);
    }, 9000);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to pass this resultId in other function which will setup timer and then you will be able to use direct values.

Comment: var status = checkStatusOfRequest(requestId);
    if(status=='downloadReady')
    {
     clearInterval(status);
    }
    }, 9000);

Comment: If status is ready, It should stop the calling checkStatusOfRequest function.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get return value of 'checkStatusOfReques' in 'myVar' variable

Use below code

```
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url:"<?php echo TESTMINE_APP_URL; ?>/ajax/export-details",
    data:'paginationHash='+paginationHash+'&exportType='+exportType+'&userId='+userId,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(requestId) 
    {
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){

            var ReturnValue = checkStatusOfRequest(requestId)
             // This is your function return value
              alert(ReturnValue);

        },9000);
    }
    });
```